# Cloud foundry "cf create-service" appends nonsense to "xsappname"

Tags: security, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry

Trying to create a XSUAA service in the cloud fail because of already existing service. But actually no service exist there.

```
 -> cf create-service xsuaa application xsuaa-authentication-newsletter -c security/xs-security.json
Creating service instance xsuaa-authentication-newsletter in org CF_Dev_DP / space Customer 
as email.email@domain.com...
Service broker error: Service broker xsuaa failed with: org.springframework.cloud.servicebroker.exception.ServiceBrokerException: Application with xsappname com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296 already exists. To create a new service instance, ensure that the xsappname specified in your application's xs-security.json file together with the selected service plan of the UAA service broker lead to a new appid. To update an existing service instance, use the update-service command instead.
FAILED
```

The error states that there is a service with the name "com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296". The contents of xs-security.json are following:

```
{
   "xsappname": "com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter",
    ...
}
```

cf appends a weird "!t36296" at the end of the name.
All of the following deletion-attempts result in a "does not exist":

```
-> cf delete -f 'com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296'
App com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296 does not exist.

-> cf delete -f 'com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter'
App com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter does not exist.

-> cf delete-service -f 'com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296'
Service com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter!t36296 does not exist.

-> cf delete-service -f 'com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter'
Service com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter does not exist.

-> cf delete-service -f 'xsuaa-authentication-newsletter'
Service xsuaa-authentication-newsletter does not exist.
```

Clearly there exist none of the apps or services, but also it could not be created because of already existing one. I could not find any similar problem on the web. I would appreciate every help or hint you could provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This error indicates that there is a XSUAA service instance already created with the same name. However it could be in a different cloud foundry space / org / subaccount, which you don't have access to. Thus you can not view that instance, neither you can delete it.
2. I would recommend you to add a prefix / suffix to `xsappname`, which will make it unique. As an example, you can use a prefix of `org-space-` so that your `xsappname` looks like this - `org-space-com-fressnapf-microservices-newsletter`. You can try some other prefix / suffix as well, just make sure that they make the `xsappname` unique.
3. The weird thing appended to the `xsappname`, let's call it suffix, can be broken down into three components. First component - `!` is just a delimiter added by XSUAA to get the suffix from `xsappname`. Secod component - `t` is an identifier of service plan, in your case it is `tenant` service plan (You may have `b` for `broker` etc.). Third and the last component - `36296` is just a running index added by XSUAA. Overall this suffix is added by XSUAA and utilized by XSUAA for some internal purposes. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Isn't it an issue ?! I can create a XSUAA service instance in my space and then update it as long as I quote the xsappname  of the other customer (I just tried and seems to have worked - sorry "myxsuaa-1234" if you read this).